# CSS calc() rounding

Tags: css, rounding, css-calc

This problem is similar to [Chrome 37 calc rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662159/chrome-37-calc-rounding)

But the real problem was a bit more complicated, and the solution provided doesn't work for this case:

```css
#outerDiv, #leftDiv, #middleDiv, #rightDiv{
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
}
#leftDiv, #rightDiv{
    width: 20px;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: green;
}
#outerDiv{
    width: 100.5px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: red;
}
#middleDiv{
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: blue;
    left: 20px;
}
#leftDiv{
    left: 0;
}
#rightDiv{
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerDiv">
    <div id="leftDiv">L</div>
    <div id="middleDiv">M</div>
    <div id="rightDiv">R</div>
</div>
```

Result in Chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCLbB.jpg

To explain a bit more: The width of the outerDiv is dependant on random amount of text, which is in another div which is also inside the outerDiv. The left and right divs contain an image, so their width is static.

The current solution we have is to change the calc to: calc(100% - 40px **+ 1px**); Is there any better solution?

Comment: The the user proposing closure: the problem is the visibility of the red line in Chrome.  The question is how to cover #outerDiv without overlap by the inner divs.

Comment: There is at least a nice comparison about the horrible browser differences regarding rounding : http://cruft.io/posts/percentage-calculations-in-ie/

Comment: I know this is quite old, but that issue still appears on Safari (MacOS). Is there any work around that works for all browsers? Adding 1px makes it look strange in browserswith good working calc() like Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed in Chrome some time ago.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=448796&q=label%3ACr-Blink&colspec=ID+Pri+M+Week+ReleaseBlock+Cr+Status+Owner+Summary+OS+Modified